# What type of illustration is this with solid colors?

Tags: illustration, style-identification

What's this type of illustration called?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [quick search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=flat%20illustration&iax=images&ia=images) with **Flat Illustration** gives me plenty of similar examples, that uses simple shapes, flat (solid) colors and shadows.

[image]

It also includes similar examples with textures and gradients, some with more details.

[image]